# Global Audio in unity using photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Im trying to make a multiplayer game using photon in unity . I created a room and joined with my friend. I want to make a sound that plays for all the players , when one of the players hit a specific key . But when i'm pressing the key the sound is only heard by me . I want my friend to hear the sound and i want to hear the same sound when my friend press the key.

```
public class PlaySound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode buton;
    public AudioSource sunet;
    
    void Update()
    {
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(buton))
        {
            sunet.Play();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Call it in an RPC.

Comment: Does unity give an error or warning?

Comment: @MattiaRaffaele nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play the audio in an RPC in order for other people to hear the audio. I can't test the code out right now, but I'm sure this will work.

```
public class PlaySound : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public KeyCode buton;
    public AudioSource sunet;
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(buton))
        {
            photonView.RPC("PlayAudio", RPCTarget.All);
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void PlayAudio()
    {
        sunet.Play();
    }

}
```